# Eclipse (Java) - After creating a new package, I'm unable to add source files to it

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have a Java project open in Eclipse with a bunch of source files under the (default package). I created a new package in the project that I wanted to move all my source files into, but when I attempt to move them, nothing happens. The little package symbol for my new package is also white, unlike the usual brown package symbol. Anyone have any idea what's going on and how I can fix this?

Also, I just wanted to make sure that once I get this working I don't have to actually move my source files to any new folders (as in, where the actual files are stored in the OS). All I have to do is put them into the package inside Eclipse, but the actual files can stay where they are in the OS file system, right?

EDIT: Figured out that the source of the problem is that I only made references to my source files in Eclipse, and didn't actually copy them into it.

Comment: Did you try moving them by using Refactor -> Move? If so, did anything show up in the error log (Window -> Show View -> Error Log) when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have linked it from an external source, obviously you cannot move them around as it is going to reflect the package structure as the files reside on the disk. A quick way would be to move the files on the disk itself where the files reside, and refresh your java project. 
NOTE: you may have to change the package names manually after you have done this.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the class, move down to refractor and click on move. From there just click on the target package, and it should be moved.

Comment: Just tried this and it didn't work, but I think I found the source of the issue. When I try to move them to the new package it says "Linked resources can only be copied to projects." I guess it just won't let you do this if you only have references to your source files in Eclipse, and not the files themselves.